# how to implement reusable api-calling component in vuejs?

Tags: api, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm developing a simple vuejs app where I have a few identical APIs serving content that is parsed in a similar way. I would like to make the code to fetch the content common across the various API calls, and only have a need to pass the API endpoint to what fetches the content.

Here's my code

```
var content = new Vue({
  el: '#story',
  data: {
    loaded: [],
    current: 0,
    hasMore:"",
    nextItems:"",
    errors: []
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get("/storyjs")
    .then(response => {
      this.loaded = this.loaded.concat(response.data.content)
      this.hasMore = response.data.hasMore
      this.nextItems = response.data.nextItem
    }).catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e)
    })
  },
  methods: {
    fetchNext: function() {
      axios.get(this.nextItems)
      .then(response => {
        this.loaded = this.loaded.concat(response.data.content)
        this.hasMore = response.data.hasMore
        this.nextItems = response.data.nextItem
        this.current+=1
      }).catch(e => {
        //TODO CLEAR errors before pushing
        this.errors.push(e)
      })
    },
    next: function() {
      if (this.current+1 < this.loaded.length) {
        this.current+=1
      } else {
        this.fetchNext()
      }
    },
    prev: function() {
      this.current = (this.current-1 >= 0) ? this.current-1 : 0
    }
  },
  delimiters: ['[{', '}]']
})
```

Right now, I've replicated the above object for stories, poems, and many other things. But I would ideally like to combine them into one. Strategies I tried to search for included having a parent component as this object, but I think I'm probably thinking wrong about some of this.
Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with mixins. This is the solution I implemented.

**apiObject.js** (Reusable object)

```
var apiObject = {
    data: function() {
        return {
            loaded: [],
            current: 0,
            hasMore: "",
            nextItems: "",
            errors: []
        };
    },
    methods: {
        fetchContent: function(apiEndpoint) {
            axios
                .get(apiEndpoint)
                .then(response => {
                    this.loaded = this.loaded.concat(response.data.content);
                    this.hasMore = response.data.hasMore;
                    this.nextItems = response.data.nextItem;
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    this.errors.push(e);
                });
        },
        fetchNext: function() {
            axios
                .get(this.nextItems)
                .then(response => {
                    this.loaded = this.loaded.concat(response.data.content);
                    this.hasMore = response.data.hasMore;
                    this.nextItems = response.data.nextItem;
                    this.current += 1;
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    //TODO CLEAR errors before pushing
                    this.errors.push(e);
                });
        },
        next: function() {
            if (this.current + 1 < this.loaded.length) {
                this.current += 1;
            } else if (this.hasMore == true) {
                this.fetchNext();
            }
        },
        prev: function() {
            this.current = this.current - 1 >= 0 ? this.current - 1 : 0;
        }
    }
};
```

**story.js** (Specific usage)

```
var storyComponent = Vue.extend({
    mixins: [apiObject],
    created() {
        this.fetchContent("/story");
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: "#story",
    components: {
        "story-component": storyComponent
    },
    delimiters: ["[{", "}]"]
});
```

and then, you could either define the template in the component itself, or use the inline-template way of creating the template in the html file, which is what I did

**output.html** with all js files included

```
<div id="story">
    <story-component inline-template>
        [{loaded[current].title}]
    </story-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to tackle this, but perhaps once you reach this level of complexity in the model of the components/application state, the most sensible strategy would be to use a central state store.

See the [State Management](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html) chapter of the vue guide and possibly the excellent [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html).

There you could factor the common logic in suitable local classes/functions and call them from store actions (for async operations you have to use [actions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html), which will commit [mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html) with respective state changes at completion of the asynchronous operations.

Comment: What you suggested sounds interesting, but I don't have any common states across the objects. The only thing common is the function itself, but the content of the data is different, owing to different API endpoints. What other ways would you suggest to tackle this?